# xpath position() expression whit xml/php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a problem to read the xml file, I want to display records from 0 to 15, but don´t show anything. Here I leave the code. thanks

XML FILE:

```
<RECORDS>
<RECORD>
      <ID_EMPLEADO>671</ID_EMPLEADO>
      <NOMBRE>JUAN</NOMBRE>
      <APELLIDOS>CARMONA&nbsp;IZQUIERDO</APELLIDOS>
      <FECHA_NACIMIENTO>1948/3/2</FECHA_NACIMIENTO>
      <TIPO_EMPLEADO>FIJO</TIPO_EMPLEADO>
      <NUM_HIJOS>3</NUM_HIJOS>
</RECORD>

/****************more record**************/
</RECORDS>
```

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
$fXML = new SimpleXMLElement('empleados.xml', NULL, TRUE);
                  $aConsulta = $fXML->xpath('/RECORDS/RECORD[position() >= 0 and position() < 15] ');
                  $nombre = $aConsulta[0]->NOMBRE;
                  $apellidos = $aConsulta[0]->APELLIDOS;
                  $fechaNac = $aConsulta[0]->FECHA_NACIMIENTO;
                  $tipoEmpleado = $aConsulta[0]->TIPO_EMPLEADO;
                  $numHijos = $aConsulta[0]->NUM_HIJOS;

                  echo $nombre;
                  echo $apellidos;
                  echo $fechaNac;
                  echo $tipoEmpleado;
                  echo $numHijos;
```

Comment: `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'`. Replace those `&nbsp;` with ` `.

Comment: I missed that @Glavić answered already :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and found problem.

It seems that `&nbsp;` in xml file gives this error. I just changed to space it and everything worked.